# How to perform an update on a nested object's array inside an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to perform an update on a field which is present in a nested object in an array.

Consider this:

```
var PlatformPhotoAlbumSchema = new Schema({
  platformAlbumId: String,
  platformPhotoIds: [String]
}, { _id : false });

var SocialProfileSchema = new Schema({
  platformPhotoAlbums: [PlatformPhotoAlbumSchema]
});
```

Example:

```
{
platformPhotoAlbums: [
    {
    platformAlbumId: "a",
    platformPhotoIds: ["1","2"]
    },
    {
    platformAlbumId: "b",
    platformPhotoIds: ["3","4"]
    },
    {
    platformAlbumId: "c",
    platformPhotoIds: ["5","6"]
    }
]

}
```

1. How can I update an existing object, for e.g., platformAlbumId with "c" with platformPhotoIds: ["5","6","7"]
2. If there is no document with platformAlbumId with "c", then create a new object with platformAlbumId as "c" and platformPhotoIds: ["5","6","7"] and insert into platformPhotoAlbums.

I want to do this in one single mongodb query. Any idea how can this be done ?

Comment: have you tried using the lodash library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the looks of what you're trying to accomplish, I think there is a simpler concept to think of for what your query actually will need to do

you want to push a new object into an array of objects that looks like

```
{
  platformAlbumId: "c",
  platformPhotoIds: ["5","6"]
}
```

and (before doing that) remove all preexisting items in the array that match a find for `platformAlbumId: "c"`

#### Edit:

actually better than that, you should be able to use `findAndModify` command with the query of your `platformAlbumId` values, update set with your new `platformPhotoIds` values, and `upsert` bool set to true http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/